# Ajax, jQuery and Wordpress

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm having trouble getting AJAX and jQuery to work with WP, and wondering if someone can point me in the right direction.

I have a form, and I want to pass the data from the form to a PHP function, where the data is returned and a `<div>` is created with the data manipulated by a PHP function. I've got a version working outside of WP, but I can't seem to port it.

I've followed many tutorials, and nothing seems to work. I've got the following code, it should simply create an alert window with the data from the form , with "hello" prepended, but the JS function never even gets called. It keeps adding `?name=name` to the page URL.

I've also tried creating a seperate JS file, and loading the script with..

```
wp_enqueue_script(
'myaddwordscript',
plugins_url() . '/MyPlugin/script.js',
array( 'jquery' )
```

Any help getting it to work is greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Addword
 * Plugin URI: Addword
 * Version: 1.0
 */


/**
 * Make sure jquery is loaded
 */
function add_to_header() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery'); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_to_header' );


/**
 * Add shortcode to show form and script
 */

function add_word( ) {      

$script = "
<script>
jQuery('#ajax_form').bind('submit', function() {
    alert('clicked');
    var form = jQuery('#ajax_form');
    var data = form.serialize();
    data.action = 'add_word_to_form'
    jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
        alert(data);           
    });
    return false;
});
</script>";

$form ='
<form class="form" id="ajax_form">                            
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  placeholder="Word Goes Here" required="">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitaddword">
</form>';

return $script.$form;


}
add_shortcode( 'addword', 'add_word' );


/** 
 * Set up AJAX call to add word
 */
add_action("wp_ajax_add_word_to_form", "add_word_to_form");
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_add_word_to_form", "add_word_to_form");

function add_word_to_form ($data)
{
    return "Hello".$data;

}


?>
```

Comment: Two things I noticed are that it looks like your bind function call is not properly closed, and you need to make sure you account for jQuery running in noConflict mode. See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers

Comment: @czerspalace - Oops. I've edited my original post, but I am still getting the same error. Thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console? Another possible issue is that your add_shortcode callback function should return a string instead of echo'ing https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: @czerspalace Thanks for looking into it. I've no errors in the console, and I've changed the shortcode to return instead of echoing (in my OP too), but still no joy!

Comment: It seems the button isn't binding. If I add `alert('clicked');` as the first line in the .bind function, before grabbing the form data, the alert never opens.

Comment: the first argument for `bind` should be an *event type*, not an element selector.

Comment: @Milo thanks. I've changed it to `jQuery('#ajax_form').bind('click', 'submit', function() {` But it's still not calling.

Comment: still not quite right - `jQuery('#ajax_form').bind('submit', function() {`

Comment: Oops I missed that when I edited the original post. I've edited it to show the most recent edit.

Comment: jQuery `.bind()` [is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/bind/). Please use `.on( 'submit', etc` or go with the short version: `.submit(`.

Comment: You won't be using this sitewide though will you? Because that's what's going on with the answer you've accepted.

Comment: @Jack no, only on one page, but I will be adding the script and form via a shortcode, so it won't load unnecessary.

Comment: Oh right, i see. GL

Comment: @Kaiser - didn't know that. I will look at changing the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your javascript code with document.ready, and if it works I would suggest going back to putting this in an external file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#ajax_form').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('Here');
        var form = jQuery('#ajax_form');
        var data = form.serialize();
        data.action = 'add_word_to_form'
        jQuery.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', data, function(response) {
            alert(data);           
        });
        //return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Perfect. So it was trying to bind before the page had loaded properly. Thanks!